# display contenute POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to display the contents of the `POST` variable, but my output is empty.

```
<?php
 $dir = '/var/www/devData/test';

 // create new directory with 777 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
  mkdir ($dir, 0777);
 }


         $stringData =  print_r($_POST['data'], true);
         $file = "/var/www/devData/test/ciao.txt"; 
         $fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
         $fla = 0;

        $arr = array();
        $i = 0;
        while(!feof($fh)) {
                    $theData = fgets($fh, filesize($file));
                    array_push($arr,$theData);
                    //echo $arr[$i]; 
                    $i++;
         }
         echo $stringData;


         fclose($fh); 



 ?>
```

When I call the function `fwrite`, the variable `$stringData` is stored into the file.

This is the function that calls the php file:

```
$.post("JS/foo.php", {data: options_label}, function(result){alert(options_label) }, "json");
```

where `options_label` is an array.

I tried to use `decode_json` and so on, but `$stringData` is still empty.

Comment: the contenute of the variable $stringData

Comment: But that's why I asked... what do you mean by "contenute" ?

Comment: i want to know the contenute like string because when i write into the file the contnute of the string is correctly stored and is in this form: 90;Aloof;0.16;0.35;-0.01;0.3;0.25;0.32;

Comment: Note 2 things: 1)you're not actually modifying `$stringData` in your `while` loop, just changing `$arr`; and 2) incrementing `$i` is useless as is because your loop doesn't depend on the value of `$i` to stop.

Comment: i know ;) the string will be manipulate after

Comment: @Edivad I think you mean "contents", not "contenute" as that could be Italian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies here:

```
$stringData =  print_r($_POST['data'], true);
```

If you want to store the contents of $_POST in file.txt you should convert $_POST['data'] to a string like so:

```
$stringData = "";

foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key=>$val) {
    $stringData .= $key . ": " . $val . "\n\r";
}
```

Comment: Matt i can store alrady the contenute of the $stringData into the file i just want to display it and manipulate it after

Comment: the output is still NULL
<?php
 
 
  $stringData = "";

  foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key=>$val) {
    $stringData .= $key . ": " . $val . "\n\r";
  }
 
 
   $stringData = "";
         $stringData = $_POST['data'];
         $file = "/var/www/devData/test/ciao.txt"; 
         $fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
  
         fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   var_dump( $stringData);
         fclose($fh); 

 
 
 ?>

Comment: Not sure if I can be of any help then. Sorry, mate.